# Spring Integration JMS does not shut down

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-jms, spring-dsl

I have a service which is intended to consume messages from a JMS queue.  This code never seems to exit on shutdown and gets stuck in a loop around line 565 of `org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer`.

Any idea it would do that?  Here is the relevant configuration:

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    public ConnectionFactory myConnectionFactory() {
        ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
        ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy activeMQPrefetchPolicy = new ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy();
        activeMQPrefetchPolicy.setQueuePrefetch(0);  // 1 message per connection, no prefetch
        connectionFactory.setPrefetchPolicy(activeMQPrefetchPolicy);
        connectionFactory.setBrokerURL("tcp://" + jmsSettings.getHost() + ":" + jmsSettings.getPort());
        return connectionFactory;
    }

@Bean 
    public JmsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter messageSource() {
        DefaultMessageListenerContainer defaultMessageListenerContainer = Jms.container(myConnectionFactory(), "incoming.queue")
                .maxConcurrentConsumers(jmsSettings.getMaxConcurrentConnections())
                .get();
        return Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(defaultMessageListenerContainer)
            .get();
    }
```

A thread dump yields a ton of information.  I believe this is the relevant chunk.

```
"DefaultMessageListenerContainer-1": awaiting notification on [1f9c4a73]
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at org.apache.activemq.SimplePriorityMessageDispatchChannel.dequeue(SimplePriorityMessageDispatchChannel.java:87)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.dequeue(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:452)
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageConsumer.receive(ActiveMQMessageConsumer.java:575)
at org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JmsDestinationAccessor.receiveFromConsumer(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:130)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveMessage(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:416)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:302)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The problem seems to be in this code block.  The activeInvokerCount never goes to 0, so it is stuck in the loop.
`org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer`

```
// Waiting for AsyncMessageListenerInvokers to deactivate themselves...
            while (this.activeInvokerCount > 0) {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Still waiting for shutdown of " + this.activeInvokerCount +
                            " message listener invokers");
                }
                long timeout = getReceiveTimeout();
                if (timeout > 0) {
                    this.lifecycleMonitor.wait(timeout);
                }
                else {
                    this.lifecycleMonitor.wait();
                }
            }
```

Trace logging enabled shows this when trying to shutdown.  Over and over again.

```
2017-04-26 13:23:49.127 TRACE 8752 --- [WriteCheckTimer] o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor        : tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616@49451 no message sent since last write check, sending a KeepAliveInfo
2017-04-26 13:23:49.127 DEBUG 8752 --- [yMonitor Worker] o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor        : Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
2017-04-26 13:23:50.511 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:23:51.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:23:52.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:23:53.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:23:54.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:23:55.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:23:56.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:23:57.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:23:58.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:23:59.127 DEBUG 8752 --- [WriteCheckTimer] o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor        : WriteChecker 10000 ms elapsed since last write check.
2017-04-26 13:23:59.127 TRACE 8752 --- [WriteCheckTimer] o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor        : tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616@49451 no message sent since last write check, sending a KeepAliveInfo
2017-04-26 13:23:59.127 DEBUG 8752 --- [yMonitor Worker] o.a.a.t.AbstractInactivityMonitor        : Running WriteCheck[tcp://127.0.0.1:61616]
2017-04-26 13:23:59.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:24:00.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:24:01.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:24:02.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:24:03.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
2017-04-26 13:24:04.512 DEBUG 8752 --- [n(12)-127.0.0.1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Still waiting for shutdown of 1 message listener invokers
```

Comment: Take a thread dump to see what the invoker thread is doing.

Comment: The relevant chunk is above.  There is obviously more in the dump, but it did not seem relevant.

Comment: It turns out this is related to the custom prefetch policy on my connection factory.  Once I remove that, everything works as normal.  @GaryRussell Any ideas why that prefetch policy is not playing nice?

Comment: FYI, the intention of this config was to allow for a multi-threaded consumption of messages, without any consumer blocking if one of the messages happens to take longer to "consume" (aka process with some business logic).  Is there a better way to configure this with the DSL?

Comment: No ideas about the prefetch, sorry; you can simply increase the concurrency (`concurrency`, or `concurrentConsumers` and `maxConcurrentConsumers`) the container will adjust the concurrency up/down based on demand (but don't use a caching connection factory with variable concurrency - see the DMLC javadocs).

Comment: Apparently this doesn't work with prefetch=0.  Must some kind of bug.  This seems to be the exact issue I'm seeing.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5409

Comment: Interesting that it's closed without a fix; I would still consider it a bug since they are not complying with the `receive(timeout)` contract. That said, the `Jms` container factory method creates a DMLC with `sessionTransacted="true"` by default - which is required when using a DMLC to avoid message loss. So their "work around" should have worked for you. You said you are using the "latest" `5.7`. It looks to me like the latest is `5.14.5`.

Comment: You are correct.  I was googling apachemq-core and came up with that number.  5.14.5 is the latest.  Apparently this API is not compatible with my mq server version, so it looks like I need to explore upgrading or using the workaround in the previously linked issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the thread that is "...stuck in a loop around line 565..." but if it's doing as you say, perhaps the thread is stuck in activemq - the default `receiveTimeout` is 1 second (and you don't appear to have changed it).

If you turn on TRACE logging, you'll get a log message each time we try to receive a message and timeout without receiving one. If you don't see such messages when you are in this state, it would indicate a problem with ActiveMQ.

Comment: I added the relevant code above (from the Spring classes).  I believe it's that worker thread that I posted that isn't closing which seems to be causing the infinite loop.  Why would that be?

Comment: I understand that, but I need the stack trace to confirm the shutdown is being invoked via the listener adapter `destroy()`. As I said, that invoker thread is currently in activemq and won't respond to the shutdown until it exits the receive. That should happen within one second; if it doesn't (and you don't see the trace log I mentioned) then the problem is in activemq. What version are you using?

Comment: I just updated to the latest activemq API -- 5.7.0.  I am still seeing the problem.  I'll post a full thread dump.

Comment: Well, the thread dump is too large to post.  I'll try to trim it up a bit to get it under the character limit.  Is there a particular thread I should look for?

Comment: Did you enable the TRACE logging as I suggested? You can post large dumps to a github gist or somplace like pastebin.

Comment: log trace added above

Comment: Given that you are not seeing logs like this... `...TRACE...Consumer [ActiveMQMessageConsumer...did not receive a message` every second, and, assuming you haven't changed the `receiveTimeout` (as your configuration shows), it looks like there is some bug in the activemq client; the thread can only react to the shutdown when the `receive(timeout)` call exits (at `receiveFromConsumer(JmsDestinationAccessor.java:130)`).

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a duplicate of https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5409. According to the ticket:

> **Gary Tully added a comment - 24/Aug/15 10:19**
>   Use a client transaction (so a transacted session) and use destination
>   policy entry usePrefetchExtension=false on the broker for the
>   destination in question. In this way you can have a prefetch of 1, and
>   only one message will get dispatched till the consuming transaction
>   commits. With the default usePrefetchExtension=true, when the first
>   message is delivered to the consumer another gets queued up